# ArcMap Raster Calculator with Python code

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, indentationerror

I'm trying use raster calculator that can export a raster to do different average values for for multiple layers. For example, I want to do averages for only the values and layers that are greater than 0. I'm trying to input Python code but it keeps failing. Here is a video where I try and explain my project if you need more context. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bt6ecPGjjDA&t=24s

I've also tried putting single quotes on the line but there is still a syntax error.

```
>>> import arcpy
... from arcpy.sa import *
... f1 = arcpy.Raster("S:/npenme2/Faunalyze\Feature_KB3_Right_Radius_14497/value")
... f2 = arcpy.Raster("S:/npenme2/Faunalyze\Feature_KB1_Right_Radius_14471_RC11/value")
... f3 = arcpy.Raster("S:/npenme2/Faunalyze\Feature_KB4_Right_Radius_14510/value")
... if value > 1:
...     outraster = (f1 + f2 + f3)/3
... else:
...     outraster = (f1 + f2 +f3)/3 - 1
...     f123 = f1 + f2 + f3
... outraster = Con(f123 > 0, f123 / 3, f123 / 3 - 1)
... outraster.save(S:/npenme2/Faunalyze/rasterCalc)
... 
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 12)
>>>
```

I've also tried SQL on the actual raster calculator tool with this query. But it too does not work:

```
Con("Feature_KB3_Right_Radius_14497" + "Feature_KB4_Right_Radius_14510" + "Feature_KB1_Right_Radius_14471_RC11">0,(("Feature_KB3_Right_Radius_14497" + "Feature_KB4_Right_Radius_14510" + "Feature_KB1_Right_Radius_14471_RC11")/3), ("Feature_KB3_Right_Radius_14497" + "Feature_KB4_Right_Radius_14510" + "Feature_KB1_Right_Radius_14471_RC11")/3-1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong and where `IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 7)`. You need to [indent](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) lines in your if clause:

```
if value > 1:
    outraster = (f1 + f2 + f3)/3
else:
    outraster = (f1 + f2 +f3)/3 - 1
```

However, this code won't do what you want it to. You need to use `Con`:

```
f123 = f1 + f2 + f3
outraster = Con(f123 > 0, f123 / 3, f123 / 3 - 1)
outraster.save('S:/npenme2/Faunalyze/rasterCalc')
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry I accidentally copied my previous edit. I fixed the indentation error. I added the con statement but I'm still getting an error. I updated my question.

Comment: The `if value > 1` won't work, that is what the `Con` replaces, remove it. Also, you didn't quote the filepath, see edit.